# embed youtube video not working for some video like vevo

Tags: html, video, youtube, embed

I have a problem with this code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<embed width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/v/_Yhyp-_hX2s"> 

</body>
</html>
```

it work on "try it yourself" on w3school.com but not work in my page, neither in a blank html page. I have this problem only with some video like vevo

Comment: have you tried using iframe instead of embed ?

Comment: This worked for me in a blank html document. Please provide more detailed description of what is happening as well as how you are hosting your website thank  you.

Comment: @xXNebulaNinjaXx it show YouTube player with "this video is unavailable"

Comment: @Leo yes i tried with embed, iframe and object, ever the same result

Comment: What country are you in

Answer (score 1):

There is actually nothing wrong with you code!

As soon as you host it it'll work. If you're on Linux try to copy the html file to "/var/www/html/" and in your browser type: "localhost/yourfilename.html". It should work!

(You'll need something like apache running).

Comment: why it work with other normal youtuber's video on YouTube?

Comment: You can take the exact same code from @gabriele. See this link for an example:
https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/cbf7a0ac

Answer (score 0):

Embed tag sometimes making problems on bbc and youtube. Try iframe tag.
[see also](https://youtubeembedcode.com/en/)